# Delete unused persistent data without reference

Tags: ios, core-data, persistent-storage

I have an app which communicates with a server. In this app I have a tableview in which I display several people from my company (their first and last name and their profile image).

Every time the tableview opens or needs to refresh, I fetch the user list from my server. These users will all have an image_name, which I try to look up in an array on the app itself. If I can't find it there, I load it from the documents dir, if I can't find it there either I download it from my server and save in locally on the device to prevent future downloads.

This works very well and it's a very easy way to manage the users and their images, it also makes sure that I download an image only once if several users have the same image (e.g. the company logo when they haven't uploaded an image yet).

The problem is that I don't keep a reference to these users so the app has no clue which user uses which image OR even if an image is still in use.

So when person A has image X it will be downloaded to the iPhone. If user A then changes his image to Y, the app will download and display image Y correctly. However, image X will never get deleted from the persistent data.

I ask you, the stackoverflow community, what's the best way to handle this?

1. Should I start keeping a reference to my users so I can also keep a reference to the old image?
2. Is there any way to find the timestamp of the last time and image was read from the documents dir?
3. Should I store the image names in coreData and all the references to them? (some kind of custom ARC logic)
4. ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At some point in time you have the list of used images, at this point in time you also have a list of images saved to disk. Once per day you can take this information and, on a background thread, do a comparison of the used and saved and delete them. This shouldn't require any additional data storage.

If you wanted to allow images to hang around for a while after they stop being used you can 'touch' the file (update the `fileModificationDate`) each time you use the file and then later you can check the modification dates of all images and delete on that basis.

Comment: The fileModificationDate was exactly what I was looking for! I didn't know it even existed.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a prefix to the image that you download and when you fetch images, check all images in persistent storage for this prefix and then remove if there are any. You should only need to delete (maximum) one image every time your client fetches, which wouldn't be too heavy on the client.